# how can i log a network cache with python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

i need to get the network logs to get a spaciel changing link.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
s = requests.Session()
ur = 'https://sdarot.tv/watch/6541-lois-clark-the-new-adventures-of-superman/season/2/episode/2'

ss = s.get(ur, headers= headers, proxies = proxies)
time.sleep(31)
print(ss.headers)
```

thats my code already tell me what to change

Comment: Please specify what output you are getting with this code.

Comment: A mp4 media link